# Django and react login with google authentication

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, google-authentication, django-allauth

I was trying set up google authentication with react frontend and django rest framework backend. I set up both the frontend and backend using this two part tutorial, [PART1](https://medium.com/@pratique/social-login-with-react-and-django-i-c380fe8982e2)  & [PART2](https://medium.com/@pratique/social-login-with-react-and-django-ii-39b8aa20cd27). When I try to login with google in the frontend I get `POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/google-login/ 400 (Bad Request)` I think it's because my google api needs an access token and an authorization code to be passed. After debugging the react js, I noticed the response I get from google doesn't have an authorization code. I suspect because `responseType` is `permission`(by default), Source:[React login props](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-login) , instead of `code`. I was wondering how would you change the response type in react? (I'm not even sure if this alone is the issue)

Here's my backend code

In my views.py file

```
class GoogleLogin(SocialLoginView):
    adapter_class = GoogleOAuth2Adapter
    callback_url = "http://localhost:3000"
    client_class = OAuth2Client
```

in my urls.py

```
path('google-login/', GoogleLogin.as_view(), name='google-login'),
```

for my front end

/Components/login.js

```
const googleLogin = async (accesstoken,code) => {
    console.log(accesstoken)
    let res = await cacaDB.post(

      `google-login/`,
      {
        access_token: accesstoken,
        code: code 
      }
    );
    console.log(res);
    return await res.status;
};


const responseGoogle = (response) => {
    console.log(response.code);
    googleLogin(response.accessToken, response.code);

    }
return(
<div className="App">
                <h1>LOGIN WITH GOOGLE</h1>
      
                <GoogleLogin
                clientId="client_id"
                buttonText="LOGIN WITH GOOGLE"
                onSuccess={responseGoogle}
                onFailure={responseGoogle}
                />
            </div>
)
```

I want to save the user in the database and have them stay logged in, in the front end.

This [Post](https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-build-google-social-login-in-django-rest-framework-and-nuxt-auth-and-refresh-its-jwt-token-752601d7a6f3) explains the login flow behind the scene. Here's [Login flow image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oj8Xa.png) I'm basically stuck on returning code and accesstoken(I can return this successfully) step.

Here's my list of questions,

1. How do I return code from google?
2. I have knox token set up, can I
   use it instead of the JWT tokens?
3. Does the `class GoogleLogin(SocialLoginView)`, take care of the steps of validating the access token and code with google and creating the user with that email in database?

Would really appreciate your inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After investigating a bit on my end, I think I *might* have a solution that works for you.

I've messed with OAuth before, and it's quite tricky sometimes because it has to be robust. So a bunch of security policies usually get in the way.

I'll provide my full step-by-step, since I was able to get it working, trying my best to match what you posted.

Firstly, to have a clean slate, I went off [the example code linked in the tutorials](https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth). I cloned and built the project, and did the following:

- Creating a new project on GCP

  - Configured the OAuth consent screen

    - I set the User type to "internal". This options may not be available if you're not using an account under GSuite (which I am). "External" should be fine though, just that "internal" is the easiest to test.
  - Created a OAuth 2.0 Client

    - Added `http://localhost:3000` to the "Authorized JavaScript origins" and "Authorized redirect URIs" sections
- Register a Django superuser

  - Registered a `Site`, with value of `localhost:8000` for both fields.
  - Went into the admin panel, and added a `Social Application` with `Client ID` and `Secret Key` as the "Client ID" and "Client Secret" from GCP, respectively. I also picked the localhost site that we added earlier and added it to the right hand box. (**I left `Key` blank**)

[Example of my Application Page](https://i.ibb.co/zfRr9Tr/social-application.png)

- Filled in the `clientId` field in `App.js`, in the params of the `GoogleLogin` component.

Here's where I ran into a bit of trouble, but this is good news as I was able to reproduce your error! Looking at the request in the network inspector, I see that for me, no body was passed, which is clearly the direct cause of the error. But looking at `App#responseGoogle(response)`, it clearly *should* pass a token of some sort, because we see the line `googleLogin(response.accessToken)`.

So what is happening is that accounts.google.com is NOT returning a proper response, so something is happening on their end, and we get an invalid response, but we fail silently because javascript is javascript.

After examining the response that Google gave back, I found this related SO post that allowed me to fix the issue, and **interestingly, [the solution to it was quite simple: Clear your cache](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48434744/12032660).** I'll be honest, I'm not exactly sure why this works, but I suspect it has something to do with the fact that development is on your local machine (`localhost`/`127.0.0.1` difference, perhaps?).

You can also try to access your site via incognito mode, or another browser, which also worked for me.

> I have knox token set up, can I use it instead of the JWT tokens?

I don't think I have enough knowledge to properly answer this, but my preliminary research suggests no. AFAIK, you should just store the token that Google gives you, as the token itself is what you'll use to authenticate. It seems that Knox replaces Django's `TokenAuthentication`, which means that Knox is in charge of generating the token. If you're offloading the login work to Google, I don't see how you could leverage  something like Knox. However, I could be very wrong.

> Does the `class GoogleLogin(SocialLoginView)`, take care of the steps of validating the access token and code with google and creating the user with that email in database?

I believe so. After successfully authenticating with Google (and it calls the backend endpoint correctly), it seems to create a "Social Account" model. An example of what it created for me is below. It retrieved all this information (like my name) from Google.

[Example of my "Social Accounts" page](https://i.ibb.co/bJHJWPp/social-accts.png)

As for how to retrieve the login from the browser's local storage, I have no idea. I see no evidence of a cookie, so it must be storing it somewhere else, or you might have to set that up yourself (with React `Provider`s, `Service`s, or even `Redux`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed response. I did tried to do the steps you recommended but ended up getting the same error. However, I've looked into the networks like you did and found out that the reason it was failing was due to `"non_field_errors": [ "View is not defined, pass it as a context variable"]`. I found out that this was due to a version conflict with djangorestframework (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64194551/google-authentication-using-django-rest-auth-and-allauth). After downgrading djangorestframework to 3.11.0. It successfully worked.